# Use Browserify to generate HTML from Markdown

Tags: markdown, browserify

I'd like to generate some HTML in my build process from Markdown. I see a couple of Markdown transforms for Browserify  (eg [Markdownify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdownify) and [browserify-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-markdown) ). However, as I understand it, these both work like this:

1. `require()` the Markdown file in a Javascript file
2. The script now has the contents of the file as HTML
3. Append this to the DOM somewhere.

In other words, the HTML page will load, then the content will be added by Javascript. I'd prefer the HTML page to already contain the Markdown content, pre-rendered.

Is there a way to achieve this in Browserify, or will I have to set up a build process using Gulp or similar?